# Pyechant and Webtext library issue

Tags: python, nltk, libraries

i'm new to python and i'm following a book Python 3 with NLTK (CookBook) I've successfully intall nltk package by writing **pip install nltk** in Cmd. now iam trying to install webtext and pyechant library same like this but i'm getting this problem:
[image]

Also this is the code and these are the errors i'm getting
Code:

```
from nltk.collocations import TrigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.metrics import TrigramAssocMeasures
words = [w.lower() for w in webtext.words('singles.txt')]
tcf = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
tcf.apply_word_filter(filter_stops)
tcf.apply_freq_filter(3)
print(tcf.nbest(TrigramAssocMeasures.likelihood_ratio, 4))
```

Error:

```
    File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/cook book/ch1(15).py", line 3, in <module>
        words = [w.lower() for w in webtext.words('singles.txt')]
  NameError: name 'webtext' is not defined
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

from nltk.corpus import webtext

and then also make sure you download it:

nltk.download('webtext')